# Delete file security issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, file-io

I use fileUpload control and i can save the image but when i try to delete it gives a security error like this :

Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

it works in my localhost but not in web.
I tried to add many kind of stuff to web config file but it didnt work i dont know why.
Why i can save file but cant delete. It might be about System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission maybe... here is my code :

```
    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imgLogo.ImageUrl))
            {
                int index = imgLogo.ImageUrl.LastIndexOf('.');
                string fileExt = imgLogo.ImageUrl.Substring(index);
                string defPath = Business.DefinitionsData.getDefaultLogoPath();
                string entId = ((xOrgProject.DataAccess.EnterpriseUserTable)Session["Enterprise"]).EnterpriseUserId.ToString();
                string FullPath = Server.MapPath(defPath) + entId + fileExt;

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FullPath);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    file.GetAccessControl();
                    file.Delete();
                    Business.DefinitionsData.UpdateEntLogoPath(int.Parse(entId), null);
                    imgLogo.ImageUrl = null;
                    imgLogo.Visible = false;
                    btnDelete.Visible = false;
                    btnUpload.Visible = true;
                    Fu1.Enabled = true;
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Kaldırıldı.";
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        { StatusLabel.Text = ex.Message; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it runs fine locally the issue is most likely due to the configuration on the web server.  Or in my experience this has often been the case.

Have you tried modifying the trust level in the machine.config file on the web server?

Also what authentication are you using on the web server?

Running it locaally you will have access to your machine but if you are using impersonation on the web server that anonymous account ID may not have the relevant server permissions to delete files which will throw a security exception.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer, i got my solution. I have wrote this code in uploading button click event then its solved. I wasnt disposing before. but now its good. thanks again.

System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(save);

img.Dispose();